# How to have two fallback image placeholders

Tags: javascript, html

This works really well for filling a placeholder in place of an image that doesn't exist.

`<img src="cantfind.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://placehold.it/600x600?text=No Picture'">`

What I was curious about is if there was a way to do two placeholders within the onError event. So I tried doing this but the Javascript isn't coming to me. any ideas? I tried assigning the urls to variable, but I'm not sure how to check for if the first placeholder fails without doing some messy xhr request or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "two placeholders"? Do you mean a 2nd placeholder if the 1st placeholder doesn't exist? You'd probably have to write a recursive function for this, to look through an array of possible src values, increasing the index each time it is called. At the moment, it's too broad though and you haven't posted the code that you've tried that isn't working. Do that and then we'll be able to assist you further.

Comment: Ah, I like the idea of using an array. The code I was working with was going no where so that's why I didn't share it. I'll come back after lunch with some code of I can't get it working after what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the current `src` equals one of the placeholders and assign a new url accordingly:

```js
onerror="
    var p1='http://.......', p2='http://......'; 
    if (this.src == p1) this.src = p2; else if (this.src != p2) this.src = p1;
"
```

Comment: I chose this one, because it is a more accurate answer to the question, however, I really like the other question's answer too as it can be used to stack a huge array of images if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it via recursive event handling... try loading and if it errors, then try loading the first element from the array, and set it to error with the next index on failure, until you hit an index that is out of range, at which point stop.

This caters for any number of defined placeholders in the sources array.

```
<img id="img" src="example.jpg" onerror="loadNextImage(0);" alt="logo image">
<script>
var imagesDir = 'path/to/images/directory/';
var sources = [ '01.jpg', 'test.gif', 'bamf.jpg', 'foobar.jpg' ];
var index = 0;

function loadNextImage(index) {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    if (index < sources.length) {
        console.log('Index:', index, sources[index]);
        image.onerror = function() { loadNextImage(index + 1); };
        image.src = imagesDir + sources[index];
    } else {
        image.alt = 'No suitable image found to display';
    }
}
</script>
```